# Matching controls in case of staggered Difference in difference estimator

Tags: logistic, panel-data, difference-in-difference, propensity-scores, matching

I would like to match firms on industry , total assets and few other variables using propensity matching score or any other matching technique but problem is companies adopted policy at different time and baseline period(1 year before policy adoption) will be different for different companies so using psmatch2 etc. Or any other matching technique I have to make sure companies matched 1 year before policy adoption. How can I do it in Stata.